# How to create different account with near dev-deploy?

Tags: nearprotocol

When I tried to deploy two different contracts with dev-deploy, both contracts were deployed to the same address, there the later erasing the former.

So is there anyway to deploy multiple contracts to different addresses with dev-deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be several ways of doing this. The one I tend to do is to delete the
files inside the `neardev` folder:

- dev-account
- dev-account.env

When you delete these, the next time you deploy your contract, it will be given a new address instead of using the existing one.

### Alternative

An alternative is to create two different accounts beforehand, and deploy to each of them separately by changing `accountId`.

```
near deploy --accountId example-contract.testnet --wasmFile out/example.wasm
```

Comment: Thanks, deleting the dev-account folder works